# Can't position ul element to the right of another div

Tags: html, position

View a live version of the code here: http://jsbin.com/wonujafuji/1/
Don't worry about the images, I have them stored locally. But you'll be able to see that News is for some reason below the topbar. I would like to position it right of signindiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code: **float-left;** should be **float: left;**